# how to mark a thread complete in Java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, thread-safety, spring-scheduled

I have a spring scheduler which internally spawns multiple threads for processing multiple similar type of requests(`ExecutorService`). I keep the reference of each child thread in a static map . In some specific scenario (lets say,  Thread taking longer than expected or for any other reason) we want to kill one thread and notify back to parent thread so that it consider it complete and move forward. I have tried using `interrupt()` on the thread refernce saved in map but that didn't notified the parent thread. How can we achieve this .[image]

Comment: With a f'in black magic marker!

Comment: thanks for your 2 cents @Joker

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific on what exactly your threads are doing. Java itself does not maintain strong parent-child relationship between threads. The collaboration you wanted very likely requires you to implement. P.S. calling interrupt on a thread might not do anything - it does not mean the thread will be interrupted and stop. That again depends on what your child threads are doing, and very likely you need to capture the interruption in the child thread in order to properly abort